# How to get Spring-Batch completion status when job is launched in Asyncnorous

Tags: spring-batch

When Spring-batch jobs are launched in Asyn - How can we get completion status of job if its Successfully completed or failed.

Comment: Read the Spring-Batch SQL tables.

Comment: We run it thru shell script. We want to capture status to pass to TWS . Should we put another api to look at log tables and loop it untill job completes.

Comment: Ia can't tell you what you should or shouldn't do, that's you décision. 
If you run your batch like `java -jar batch.jar ...`, then the return of the commant ligne migh conain the batch status... I guess.

Comment: We have a shell script which uses Curl cmd to  call spring batch job. If job runs less than 3 mins we get the response, if more than 3 min we are getting timeout and job is running . So we change to Async - we need to find a way to capture when job is complted  in shell script and pass it to TWS

Comment: Ok, so create an end-point that start the job an return the job ID, then another end-point that can give you the status of a  job from the job ID.

Comment: We have this in mind - exploring any other alternate way if spring provides which can poll and send the status.  If we put a new end point to check the status we should put a loop untill we get back completion status. Is this a good way.

Comment: Do the connection with a socket, so you'll be able to keep the connection open as long as the batch run.

Comment: Connection with socket - can we do it for calling end-point thru curl cmd. We face the same issue also thru swagger. Is there a way to change the pass timeout value in curl url

Comment: Read `curl` documentation